# Check if no data returned node-fetch discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-fetch

So I'm trying to make a command for my bot that converts Minecraft usernames into `uuid`, the mojang API returns NO data when the username is not recognized, is there a way to check if no data was returned without my bot crashing?

```js
fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}?`)
    .then(Result => Result.json())
    .then(async mojang => {
        if (mojang.empty) {
            return interaction.reply({content:`No user by the name of **${username}** was found`, ephemeral: true})
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch error using [`Promise.prototype.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and adding `if/else` conditions like so:

```
fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}?`).then((response) => {
  // check if initial response is okay
  if (response && response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  } else {
    // handle the error if no initial response was sent
  }
})
.then((responseJson) => {
  // If you get the final json response, proceed
})
.catch((error) => {
 // catch any type of errors related to the promise and handle it
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Updated, also have put comments as guidelines on what the code is doing